# Reports of Cryptocurrency Exchanges faking volume trade data. Where can one find this report?

Tags: exchanges, trading, currencies, historical-trade-data, volume

In 2018 December there was a research report on cryptocurrency exchanges faking volume trade data. Where can one find this report on these exchanges? Supposedly the only 2 exchanges that had real trade volume was Bitfinex and Binance. I'd like to know what were the rest.

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://medium.com/@sylvainartplayribes/chasing-fake-volume-a-crypto-plague-ea1a3c1e0b5e) will help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All online roads seem to lead to https://www.blockchaintransparency.org